# Unable to override ApiController Methods

Tags: c#, generics

I have a base API Controller, here is a snippet:

```
public abstract class CrudController<TDto, TAdd, TEdit, TLookup> : BaseApiController
        where TDto : BaseDto, new()
        where TAdd : BaseModel
        where TEdit : BaseModel
        where TLookup : BaseModel
    {
        [NonAction] 
        protected virtual Expression<Func<TDto, bool>> CreateWhere(Guid? id)
        {
            return dto => true;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public virtual DataSet<TLookup> Query([FromUri] DtoQuery query, Guid? id = null)
        {           
            DataSet<TDto> data = DataService.Query(query, CreateWhere(id));
            return new DataSet<TLookup>(data.Records.Map<TLookup>(), data.Total);
        }
     }
```

I inherit from this ApiController class, and then want to override a single method, within the derived class:

```
public class ProductCategoryController : CrudController<ProductSubcategoryDto, ProductSubcategoryModel, ProductSubcategoryModel, ProductSubcategoryModel>
{
    protected override Expression<Func<ProductSubcategoryDto, bool>> CreateWhere(Guid? id)
    {
        return dto => dto.ProductCategoryGuid == id;
    }
}
```

But the method in the derived class is not being executed.

GET api/productcategorycontroller/query?queryetctectec is called from the view.

DataSet<>() is executed on the base class.

I then step through the code, the first line of this method calls CreateWhere() and F11 takes me a few lines up and not to the overridden method in the derived class.

BaseApiController is just an empty class that is derived from ApiController.

Comment: Is the method in the base class executed instead? Is the *call* to `CreateWhere` executed at all?

Comment: what is `BaseApiController`?

Comment: have you tried NOT using your empty class? try using `ApiController` directly

Comment: Are you certain you are getting a new instance of `ProductCategoryController` and not an instance of `CrudController<ProductSubcategoryDto, ProductSubcategoryModel, ProductSubcategoryModel, ProductSubcategoryModel>`?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was breaking on the wrong ApiController, and it was working all along.